# Create season variable in R

Tags: r, date, time

My season time is Oct 1st to March 31st of the following year. How I create a dummy variable for season to see that person exposed in and out

```
 df <- data.frame(ID= c(1:6), 
             Drug = c("A","C","A","A","B","A"),
             Start = c("01/01/2009","07/10/2010","10/10/2009","03/01/2011","03/01/2012","04/12/2010"),
             End=c("09/10/2009","04/20/2011","07/20/1010","01/01/2012","04/01/2013","09/30/2011"))
```

My output:

```
   ID Drug      Start        End Season
1   1    A 01/01/2009 09/10/2009      1
2   1    A 01/01/2009 09/10/2009      0
3   2    C 07/10/2010 04/20/2011      0
4   2    C 07/10/2010 04/20/2011      1
5   2    C 07/10/2010 04/20/2011      0
6   3    A 10/10/2009 07/20/1010      1
7   3    A 10/10/2009 07/20/1010      0
8   3    A 10/10/2009 07/20/1010      1
9   4    B 03/01/2011 01/01/2012      1
10  4    B 03/01/2011 01/01/2012      0
11  4    B 03/01/2011 01/01/2012      1
12  5    A 03/01/2012 04/01/2013      1
13  5    A 03/01/2012 04/01/2013      0
14  5    A 03/01/2012 04/01/2013      1
15  5    A 03/01/2012 04/01/2013      0
16  6    A 04/12/2010 09/30/2011      0
```

ID 1: She started from 01/01 and end 09/10.

```
[01/01, 03/31] =1

[03/31,09/10] = 0
```

ID 2: She started from 07/10 and end 04/20. I check

```
[07/10, 10/01] = 0

[10/01,03/31] = 1

[03/31, 04/20] = 0
```

ID5 She started 03/01 and ended 04/01

```
[03/01, 03/31]= 1

[03/31, 10/01] = 0

[10/01, 03/31] = 1

[03/31, 04/01] = 0
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.  So patient 2 gets three rows with seasons 0, 1, 0 because she started outside the season, went through the season, and ended outside the season?

Comment: And patient 5 gets four rows because she went through four periods (two on-season and two off-season)?

Comment: she started from 07/10/2010  and end 04/20/2011, so I check [07/10, 10/01] = 0, then [10/1, 03/31] = 1, [03/31/04/20] = 0

Comment: I would create two tables.  One of patient start/end (1 row per patient), and one of seasons (with on/off indicator) .  Then you are going to have to do a fancy join on overlap.  Otherwise without a fancy join you are left with a nested loop that is ugly but pretty straightforward.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 has a pretty good idea.  You should try that, and make it a stackoverflow question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got the ExposedIn and ExposedOut correct with the code below (note:  you need to add 'stringsAsFactors = FALSE' when you create your data frame).  However, I didn't quite have the time to work out the additional sum of entire seasons covered -- I would do that by adding another column with a date/time function that takes into account the total treatment time.

```
df$Start <- as.Date(df$Start, format = '%m/%d/%Y')
df$End <- as.Date(df$End, format = '%m/%d/%Y')
df$SeasonIn <- 274 # 275 in leap years
df$SeasonOut <- 90 # 91 in leap years
df$ExposedIn <- as.integer(as.POSIXlt(df$Start)$yday >= df$SeasonIn | 
as.POSIXlt(df$Start)$yday < df$SeasonOut)
df$ExposedOut <- as.integer(as.POSIXlt(df$End)$yday >= df$SeasonIn | 
as.POSIXlt(df$End)$yday < df$SeasonOut)
```

Hope this at least helps some.